# How to print all lines after the pattern match

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to print lines after the occurrence of `logically moving media as follows...` in my output. Note: this particular pattern can occur anywhere in the file.

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Below is my file:

```
Generating list of recommended changes ...

Proposed Change(s) to Update the Volume Configuration
=====================================================
Logically move media ID PN0960 (barcode PN0960L4) from standalone to slot 18.
Logically move media ID PN1067 (barcode PN1067L4) from standalone to slot 44.
Logically move media ID PN1080 (barcode PN1080L4) from standalone to slot 52.
Logically move media ID PN1711 (barcode PN1711L4) from standalone to slot 54.
Logically move media ID PN1728 (barcode PN1728L4) from standalone to slot 109.
Logically move media ID PN1926 (barcode PN1926L4) from standalone to slot 112.
Logically move media ID PN1933 (barcode PN1933L4) from standalone to slot 134.
Logically move media ID NY2617 (barcode NY2617L4) from standalone to slot 165.
Logically move media ID PN0016 (barcode PN0016L4) from standalone to slot 167.
Logically move media ID NY2011 (barcode NY2011L4) from standalone to slot 186.
Logically move media ID NY2021 (barcode NY2021L4) from standalone to slot 203.
Logically move media ID NY2046 (barcode NY2046L4) from standalone to slot 262.
Logically move media ID NY2222 (barcode NY2222L4) from standalone to slot 376.
Logically move media ID NY2236 (barcode NY2236L4) from standalone to slot 377.
Logically move media ID NY2290 (barcode NY2290L4) from standalone to slot 385.
Logically move media ID NY2519 (barcode NY2519L4) from standalone to slot 485.
Logically move media ID NY2017 (barcode NY2017L4) from standalone to slot 487.
Logically move media ID NY2048 (barcode NY2048L4) from standalone to slot 490.
Logically move media ID NY2133 (barcode NY2133L4) from standalone to slot 494.
Logically move media ID NY2135 (barcode NY2135L4) from standalone to slot 495.
Logically move media ID NY2149 (barcode NY2149L4) from standalone to slot 496.
Logically move media ID NY2348 (barcode NY2348L4) from standalone to slot 497.
Logically move media ID NY2371 (barcode NY2371L4) from standalone to slot 498.
Updating volume configuration ...

Processing existing media added to or moved within the robotic library by
logically moving media as follows...
        Media ID        Slot
        ========        ====
         PN0960           18
         PN1067           44
         PN1080           52
         PN1711           54
         PN1728          109
         PN1926          112
         PN1933          134
         NY2617          165
         PN0016          167
         NY2011          186
         NY2021          203
         NY2046          262
         NY2222          376
         NY2236          377
         NY2290          385
         NY2519          485
         NY2017          487
         NY2048          490
         NY2133          494
         NY2135          495
         NY2149          496
         NY2348          497
         NY2371          498


Volume configuration successfully updated.
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n '/logically moving media as follows/,$p' input.txt
```

This prints all lines matching `logically moving media as follows` til the end of the document.

Answer (score 3):

Use **fedorqui**'s solution OR:

```
sed -rn '/logically moving media as follows/,$p' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` is one of the ways:

```
$ awk '/logically moving media as follows/ {p=1} p' file
```

It looks for the `"logically moving media as follows"` text. Once it is found, the flag `p` is activated with `{p=1}`. The `p` condition at the end is then true, so the default behaviour of awk is performed, which is `{print $0}`.

It returns:

```
logically moving media as follows...
        Media ID        Slot
        ========        ====
         PN0960           18
         PN1067           44
         PN1080           52
         PN1711           54
         PN1728          109
         PN1926          112
         PN1933          134
         NY2617          165
         PN0016          167
         NY2011          186
         NY2021          203
         NY2046          262
         NY2222          376
         NY2236          377
         NY2290          385
         NY2519          485
         NY2017          487
         NY2048          490
         NY2133          494
         NY2135          495
         NY2149          496
         NY2348          497
         NY2371          498


Volume configuration successfully updated.
```